# Why is git pull needed to update a (different) branch (moving branch to latest commit without git pull)?

Tags: git, git-pull

I would gladly have written a more precise topic for this question, but I cannot express it better at the moment.

Basically, let's say you have a repo where you have several branches, say "master" and "mybranch".

So, let's say you're on master:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then you do `git pull` here; new commits are retrieved both for `master` branch, and the `mybranch`. Since you are already in branch `master`, `master` has its HEAD automatically updated by `git` to the latest received commit.

Now, let's say you change branch using checkout:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
Switched to branch 'mybranch'
Your branch is behind 'origin/mybranch' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Now this is what puzzles me - in the previous pull, (apparently) all of the latest commits - including those in `mybranch` - had been retrieved; otherwise my local git would not "know" that my local branch "is behind ... by 2 commits".

So my question is: why would I need to do "git pull" again, having a needless roundtrip to the server - when we already have those new commits for `mybranch` downloaded? Isn't there a "git update-head" or some command, which would do it locally, without a round-trip to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explanation of what happens in the first step is incorrect.  When you did `git pull` from the `master` branch, you were really doing `git pull origin master`.  This updates the local tracking branch `origin/master`, then merges this branch into your local `master` to fast-forward it.  It does not affect other branches.

If you only want to make a single round trip to the Git server, then you could try doing:

```
git fetch origin   # update all local tracking branches
# from e.g. mybranch
git merge origin/mybranch
```

Then, if you also wanted to update your local `master` branch, you would only need to checkout and merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

Note that the above two steps happened completely locally, independent of the remote Git server.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen - so that means, in the OP example, if I already did a `git pull` in `master` (which did a `git fetch` and `git merge`) - I can just do `git merge origin/mybranch` once I `git checkout mybranch`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `git pull` should be the same `git fetch` + `git merge` (unless you configure rebase to the be the default pull strategy).

Answer (score 5):

You're missing *remote-tracking branches* in the picture, that's what causes your confusion.

*(Remider : `git pull` is a convenient way of doing two operations : `git fetch` then `git merge origin/<currentBranch>`)*

When you `fetch`, you're not modifying your local branch, you're updating the remote-tracking branches which are mirrored images of remote branches.

These branches are not to be checked out or modified by you, they're used for purpose of, as you mentioned, comparisons, or other inspections.

`git pull` goes one step further than `git fetch`, though, and merges the remote-tracking branch into its local counterpart.

Which explains why you need to explicitly change branch then pull again (or simply merge) to update your other branch.

Comment: Thanks @RomainValeri - great explanation (upvoted!), however I accepted the other answer because there was a bit more command line examples.

Comment: @sdbbs No worries, Tim's answer is excellent and we all learned more in the process :-)